# how i can use wordpress website inside nodejs app

Tags: node.js, wordpress, apache

I want to use wordpress as my blogging website and main website in nodejs. Consider my website url looks like http://www.example.com in NodeJS. for blogs url http://www.example.com/blogs i want to open my wordpress blog website here. How i can achive this ?

Using wordpress module i can get posts but i want to use whole php blog website to http://www.example.com/blogs. For admin panel of blog webiste http://www.example.com/blog/wp-admin.

Comment: can you please explain which Hosting you are using for this website?

Comment: I am using DigitalOcean server with Apache2